# Issue running JavaScript with multiple elseifs

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting this JavaScript to run, any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event){

    var like = parseInt($("input:radio[name=like]:checked").val());
    var building = parseInt($("#building").val());
    var language = parseInt($("#language").val());
    var clients = parseInt($("#clients").val());
    var study = parseInt($("input:radio[name=study]:checked").val());
    var successrate = like + building + language + clients + study;

    if(successrate <= 5 ) {
      $("#csharpOut").show();
    } elseif (sucessrate >5 or <=10) {
      $("#javaOut").show();
    } elseif (sucessrate >10 or <=18) {
      $("#phpOut").show();
    } elseif (sucessrate >18 or <=20) {
      $("#rubyOut").show();
    }else {
      $("#designOut").show();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: That is `||` not `or`

Comment: and `else if` instead or `elseif`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The `elseif` is causing error in your case. It should be `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

It's `else if`, `elseif` is **not** specific to Javascript.